# Unhandled Exception: LateInitializationError: Field '_db@19320762' has not been initialized

Tags: flutter, dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sqlflite_demo/screens/product_list.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return MaterialApp(
      home: ProductList(),
    );
  }
}
```

main.dart

```
class Product {
  int? id;
  String? name;
  String? description;
  double? unitPrice;

  Product({this.name, this.description, this.unitPrice});
  Product.withId({this.id, this.name, this.description, this.unitPrice});

  Map<String,dynamic> toMap(){
    var map = Map<String,dynamic>();
    map["name"]=name;
    map["description"]=description;
    map["unitPrice"]=unitPrice;
    if(id!=null){
      map["id"]=id;

    }
    return map;
  }

  Product.fromObject(dynamic o){
    this.id = int.tryParse(o["id"]);
    this.name=o["name"];
    this.description=o["description"];
    this.unitPrice = double.tryParse(o["unitPrice"].toString());
    
  }
}
```

product.dart

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

import '../models/product.dart';

class DbHelper {
  late Database _db;

  Future<Database> get db async {
    if (_db == null) {
      _db = await initializeDb();
    }
    return _db;
  }

  Future<Database> initializeDb() async {
    String dbPath = join(await getDatabasesPath(), "etrade.db");
    var eTradeDb = await openDatabase(dbPath,version: 1, onCreate: createDb);
    return eTradeDb;
  }

  void createDb(Database db, int version)async {
    await db.execute("Create table products(id integer primary key, name text, description text, unitPrice integer)");

  }

  Future<List<Product>> getProducts() async{
    Database db = await this.db;
    var result = await db.query("products");
    return List.generate(result.length, (i){
      return Product.fromObject(result[i]);
    });
  }

  Future<int> insert(Product product)async{
    Database db = await this.db;
    var result = await db.insert("products", product.toMap());
    return result; ////////

  }

  Future<int> delete(int id)async{
    Database db = await this.db;
    var result = await db.rawDelete("delete from products where id=$id");
    return result;

  }

  Future<int> update(Product product)async{
    Database db = await this.db;
    var result = await db.update("products", product.toMap(), where: "id=?",whereArgs: [product.id]);
    return result;

  }
}
```

db_Helper.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sqlflite_demo/data/dbHelper.dart';
import 'package:sqlflite_demo/models/product.dart';
import 'package:sqlflite_demo/screens/product_add.dart';

class ProductList extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _ProductListState();
    
  }

}

class _ProductListState extends State {
  var dbHelper =  DbHelper();
  late List<Product> products;
  int productCount =0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    getProducts();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Ürün Listesi"),
      ),
      body:  buildProductList(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: (){goToProductAdd();},
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        tooltip: "Yeni Ürün Ekle",
      ),
    );
  }

  ListView buildProductList() {

    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: productCount,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position){
          return Card(
            color: Colors.pinkAccent,
            elevation: 2.0,
            child: ListTile(
              leading: CircleAvatar(backgroundColor: Colors.black12, child: Text("P"),),
             title: Text(products[position].name.toString()),
              subtitle: Text(products[position].description.toString()),
              onTap: (){},
            ),
          );
        });
  }

  void goToProductAdd() async{
    bool result = await Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>ProductAdd()));
    if(result!=null){
      if(result){
        getProducts();
      }
    }
  }

  void getProducts() async{
    var productsFuture = dbHelper.getProducts();
    productsFuture.then((data){
      this.products = data;
      productCount=data.length;
    });
  }

}
```

product_list.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sqlflite_demo/data/dbHelper.dart';

import '../models/product.dart';

class ProductAdd extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return ProductAddState();
  }

}

class ProductAddState extends State {
  var dbHelper = DbHelper();
  var txtName=TextEditingController();
  var txtDescription=TextEditingController();
  var txtUnitPrice=TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Yeni Ürün Ekle"),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            buildNameField(),buildDescriptionField(),buildUnitPriceField(),buildSaveButton()
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  buildNameField() {
    return TextField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Ürün Adı"),
      controller: txtName,
    );
  }

  buildDescriptionField() {
    return TextField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Ürün Açıklaması"),
      controller: txtDescription,
    );
  }

  buildUnitPriceField() {
    return TextField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Birim Fiyatı"),
      controller: txtUnitPrice,
    );
  }

  buildSaveButton() {
    return FlatButton(
        child: Text("Ekle"),
        onPressed: (){
          addProduct();
        },
        );
  }

  void addProduct() async{
  var result = await dbHelper.insert(Product(name: txtName.text, description: txtDescription.text, unitPrice: double.tryParse(txtUnitPrice.text)));
  Navigator.pop(context,true);
  }
}
```

product_add.dart

[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: LateInitializationError: Field '_db@19320762' has not been initialized.

This is my first project in flutter. and I have an error. can you explain that? Thanks. I dont know what happened

Comment: In db_Helper.dart in the function initState add `super.initState();` above `getProducts();`

Comment: late Database _db; remove late keyword and ry again.

Comment: @WilsonToribio It didn't work. still same

Comment: @Yashraj When I remove the word "late" I get error.  _Non-nullable instance field '_db' must be initialized. (Documentation)  Try adding an initializer expression, or a generative constructor that initializes it, or mark it 'late'._

Comment: Try : Database? db;

Comment: @Yashraj thank you for your help. I solved the problem.